# Spring Security 5 with JDBC Authentication: UserDetailsService bean is still in-memory rather than JDBC

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I'm building a Spring Security sample with JDBC authentication using Spring Boot and Kotlin. I've configured the JDBC authentication like in the documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication-jdbc):

```
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    fun configureGlobal(
            auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder,
            dataSource: DataSource
    ) {
        auth
                .jdbcAuthentication()
                .withDefaultSchema()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .withUser(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("alice")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER"))
    }
}
```

It's not clear why Spring Security still keeps InMemory UserDetailsService implementation? Line (1) below throws UsernameNotFoundException if uncommented because default UserDetailsService bean in Spring Context is InMemory implementation rather than JDBC that I just configured. It would be OK if InMemory one returned users that configured above, but it doesn't.

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService

@SpringBootApplication
class JdbcAuthenticationSampleApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val context = runApplication<JdbcAuthenticationSampleApplication>(*args)

    // default UserDetailsService bean is still InMemory implementation
    val defaultUserDetailsService = context.getBean(UserDetailsService::class.java)
    println("Default UserDetailsService: $defaultUserDetailsService")
    // "alice" can't be found by it and it throws UsernameNotFoundException
    //defaultUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername("alice") // (1)

    // I could get JDBC UserDetailsService only by this improper way
    val authenticationConfiguration = context.getBean(AuthenticationConfiguration::class.java)
    val authenticationManager = authenticationConfiguration.authenticationManager as ProviderManager
    val authenticationProvider = authenticationManager.providers[0] as DaoAuthenticationProvider
    val getUserDetailsService = DaoAuthenticationProvider::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("getUserDetailsService")
    getUserDetailsService.isAccessible = true
    val jdbcUserDetailsService = getUserDetailsService.invoke(authenticationProvider) as UserDetailsService
    println("JDBC UserDetailsService: $jdbcUserDetailsService")
    // should find "alice" now
    println("User: ${jdbcUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername("alice")}")

    context.close()
}
```

and the output is:

```
Default UserDetailsService: org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager@6af87130
JDBC UserDetailsService: org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager@22a4ca4a
User: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@5899680: Username: alice; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
```

And here's my `build.gradle.kts` for clarity, pretty standard. No more configuration other than this.

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.4.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.61"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.61"
}

group = "sample.spring.security"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}
```

Here is the test that can't even start due to UsernameNotFoundException:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
class JdbcAuthenticationSampleApplicationTests @Autowired constructor(
        val userDetailsService: UserDetailsService
) {

    @Test
    @WithUserDetails("alice")
    fun testUserDetailsService() {
        //SecurityContext can't be built due to UsernameNotFoundException
    }
}
```

The question is why there is still in-memory UserDetailService? And how can I get JDBC UserDetailsService properly?
It's worth to mention that JDBC authentication works correct when the user authenticates through log on form on UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, `UserDetailsService` bean can be taken from just configured `jdbcAuthentication()`, in addition to my original `SecurityConfig`:

```
@Bean
fun userDetailsService(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder): UserDetailsService = auth.defaultUserDetailsService
```

It's shorter and is instantiated in proper order - **after** `@Autowired fun configureGlobal(...)` because `SecurityConfig`, as a bean, itself is initialized before the beans declared inside it.

Full config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    fun userDetailsService(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder): UserDetailsService = auth.defaultUserDetailsService

    @Autowired
    fun configureGlobal(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder,
                        dataSource: DataSource) {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .withDefaultSchema()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .withUser(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("alice")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `jdbcAuthentication` ensures that a `UserDetailsService` is available for the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder.getDefaultUserDetailsService()` method.
That is why your application is working as expected when a user authenticates through the UI.

However, it does not create a `UserDetailsService` bean.
Using `context.getBean()` and `@WithUserDetails` both expect a `UserDetailsService` bean.

If you want to continue to configure `jdbcAuthentication` as above, then you can use something like `@WithMockUser` in you tests.

Alternatively, if you want to create a `UserDetailsService` bean, you can do so with the following configuration, which is similar to your configuration above.
You will need to modify the `DataSource` bean. This example simply illustrates how to use the default schema.

```
@Bean
fun dataSource(): DataSource {
    return EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .addScript("classpath:org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/users.ddl")
            .build()
}

@Bean
fun users(dataSource: DataSource): UserDetailsManager {
    val userDetailsManager = JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource)
    userDetailsManager.createUser(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("alice")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER")
            .build())
    return userDetailsManager
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Eleftheria. The point that `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` doesn't expose `UserDetailsService` bean explains the behavior. You example works well, and I upvoted it. Although, I added an alternative way, which is a bit more concise and doesn't highlight the DDL script path explicitly.